# freezing rows in filter Excel

Tags: excel, filtering

My problem seems trivial … but I have stacked in Excel.
I have a really big data sheet and to be able to work with it I applied 3 first rows as frozen (not all cells in this range are filled but sometimes it looks like:

```
C1: Shop1, 
C2: year, 
C3: cashier
....data1
....data2
```

). Then I add there a filter and when data is filtered, I can see only the first row – without row 2 and 3.
Is there any way how to make the frozen rows, frozen also for filtering? Like “untouchable” headers?

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to input the filter starting in row 3, in other words, select the entire row number 3 in your data table and click on filter. This way you maintain the top 3 rows when you filter your data.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this could be.
split the view for the top three rows and then create filter on the first row, considering each cell of the first row can be used as column header.

Then you can use the lower part of the split view to work and the top three rows will always be there.

This though not optimal but a quick solution for large sheets with more than 3-4000+  rows of data.

Hope this helps.